# How to make value constant locally?

Tags: c, constants

What I mean under that can be shown by that example:

```
char* func(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
    if (str2 != NULL) {
    ... (create some value depending on str1 and return it)
    ... (and be sure that str1 and str2 aren't change)
    }
    else
        return str1;
}
```

it works fine, but I am getting "Warning    C4090   'return': different 'const' qualifiers".

Can I somehow make strings read-only inside of function, but modifiable outside (when return) without warnings?

Comment: Do you mean the caller of `func` is expected to pass a string that is not `const` in the caller, but you want it to be `const` inside `func`? If so, you can simply change the return statement to `return (char *) str1`. This matches the pattern used by the standard library function `strstr`, and the awkwardness is due to `const` being a late addition to the C language.

Comment: By defining it as `const char* func()`? If you create another string dynamically, that can be returned too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely add `const` to a type (referenced by a pointer), but cannot (safely) remove it. So

```
char *func(char *unmodified1, char *unmodified2) {
    const char *str1 = unmodified1;
    const char *str2 = unmodified2;
    // use str1 and str2
    return unmodified1;
}
```

If you are 100% sure that in all cases it is safe to remove the `const`ness, you can cast it away

```
char *func(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
    if (str2 != NULL) {
    ... (create some value depending on str1 and return it)
    ... (and be sure that str1 and str2 aren't change)
    }
    else
        return (char*)str1;       // possible unsafe removal of const
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting this is exactly how `strchar`/`strrchar`/`strpbrk` do it so you can pass non-const `char*` arguments and modify the result but also pass `const char*` arguments without casting the argument/result